# Get string line by line android programmatically

Tags: java, android

I have this code but the problem is that this continually showing toast of each string line when I pressed my desired button.

**Like this:**

Clicked the button once:

Toast shows continually:

A

B

C

What I want is to get string from a single line once I click the button.

**Like this:**

EditText value:
A

B

C

Result first click:

A only

Result second click:

B only

Result third click:

C only

Like that

Btw this is the code I use:

```
Button checkButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.check_Button);
        checkButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    
                    EditText editBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_Text);
                    String items = editBox.getText().toString();
                    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(items);
                    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                        String line = scanner.nextLine();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), line, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    scanner.close();
                    
                }
            }
        );
```

I know it's hard to understand but please bare with me.

Comment: Why do you use a scanner.nextLine() when you have a editText()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can go for an approach like this.

```
    int clicks = 0;
    Button checkButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.check_Button);
    checkButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v) {
         EditText editBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_Text);
         String items = editBox.getText().toString();
         if (i == 0) {  
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), items , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
            i++;  
            editBox.setText("");
         } else if (i == 1) {  
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), items , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
           i++; 
           editBox.setText("");
         } else if (i==2) {
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), items , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
           i = 0;
         }  
  } 
    
}
```

Just enter a value in the editText when the value is reset after a single button click.

Answer (score 0):

```
int position=0;
EditText editText=findViewById(R.id.editText);
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            
           
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3) {
        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3) {
           if(charSequence.length()<=0)
           {
                position=-1;
           }
           else{
                position=0;
           }
           
        }
    });
Button button=findViewById(R.id.button);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v){
        int length=editText.getText().length();
        if(position==-1){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Nothing in EditText box",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }
        if(position==length){
            position=0; 
        }
        
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),editText.getText().charAt(position),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            position++;
        
    }
});
```